# Tooltips In Angular 5.1

Tags: angular

Ok, I’ve got a list of buttons sitting in my component, 'app-figures-list'

```
<div *ngFor='let figure of figures'>
  <button (click)='figureClick(figure)'>{{ figure.figureName }}</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf=‘figureToShowDetails’ id=‘figureTooltip’>
    <app-figure-tooltip></app-figure-tooltip>
</div>
```

Looks like this:

[List O' Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUYE7.png)

My desired behavior is to click the button (or hover, or any other event) and have the 'figureTooltip' div, containing  appear next to it.  Like so…

[Button With Component Appearing Next To It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bxbC.png)

My first thought was to build this as simply as possible:

1. Wire up app-figures-list and app-figure-tooltip so with the appropriate input-output properties, in this case ‘figureToShowDetails’. Assign them on the event.
2. Get the position of the calling element, in this case, the button.
3. Change the position of the div that contains  to nearby the position of the calling element.  The div that contains  will have an appropriate z-index value.

To that end, I’ve tried several different flavors of ElementRef, Renderer, Renderer2.  I won’t outline all of them here, except to say they didn’t work.

Most importantly, I had the gut sense that I was still caught in the mental model of DOM manipulation that is against the spirit of Angular.

What’s the correct approach in this case?

Comment: Maybe a bit intimidating, but you can take a look at @angular/material tooltip implementation https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tooltip/tooltip.ts

Comment: That implementation looks like it handles many, many scenarios.  This is really a beginner question: should I approach this with DOM manipulation? If true, then how?  If DOM manipulation is not the approach, then what's the approach?  Other germane things, like positioning elements in the document, are concepts I'm interested in.

Comment: For those downvoting, what's the purpose? I have simply outlined my problem, which is basic functionality,  mentioned things I've tried and asked for clarification.  I'm using the "Pretend You're Talking To A Busy Colleague" approach, "Hey, I'm trying to show a tooltip, containing a component, on an event, how would you approach that?"

Comment: Not me downvoting you, but you are likely to get a few downvotes if the answer to your question is either found easily with a quick google search or by reading a bit in the official documentation.

Comment: I had a bit in the question about how I've seen tons of heady, philosphical documentation explaining to me that DOM manipulation is the wrong way to think about things.  No crunchy examples, however.  I've done google searches, ad naseum.   Believe me, with this crowd, SO is the *last* place I want to come to.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful at all though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to add a 'tooltip' element to each button like this:

```
<div *ngFor='let figure of figures'>
  <button (click)='showTooltipForFigure(figure)'>{{ figure.figureName }}</button>
  <app-figure-tooltip *ngIf="visibleTooltipforFigure===figure">Hello!</app-figure-tooltip>
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
  figures = [{figureName:'figure1'},{figureName:'figure2'}];
  visibleTooltipforFigure=null;
  showTooltipForFigure(figure) {
      this.visibleTooltip=figure;
  }
```

With your own styling ofcourse. Here the tooltips are positioned close to the buttons, and you can add position: absolute and move them using margins.

Comment: Thanks for the stab, however, it doesn't address that I want the <app-figures-tooltip> component in the div tooltip.  I want to use the <app-figures-tooltip> elsewhere, hence it's a component.   If I have <app-figures-tooltip> instantiated on the page several hundred times, because of the loop, wouldn't that negatively affect performance?

Comment: Absolutely not. When inside an ngIf, it is only instantiated when it is in use. I'll edit to use your component instead, it really does not make a difference.

Comment: Ok, that works.  Yes, it's ridiculously simple, thank you.  I had made the erroneous assumption that instantiating a control hundreds of times would be bad, and I didn't even try it.